# Set up OSX to act as router via Internet Sharing

Tags: network, macos

I have the following network setup:

```
LAN====OSX++++Machine A
        +
        +
        ++++++Machine B
```

OSX is currently sharing an ethernet connection with A and B via an ad-hoc wireless network.  This works great, except that Machine A and Machine B can't see each other.  They can see the LAN and OSX, and OSX can see both of them.  I'm convinced some combination of ipfw and/or natd configuration options can solve this problem, but my networking knowledge is limited enough that I can't seem to Google effectively for a solution.  What do I want ipfw/natd to do for me?  How do I get them to do it?

(Obviously, I could solve this problem much more easily by the expedient of purchasing a switch, but I feel like I should know how to do this sort of things regardless.)

Comment: Can you clarify how the two machines are supposed to see each other (e.g. are they OS X computers with file sharing turned on but not showing up in each others' Finder sidebars)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable routing.  I'm pretty sure on OS X this is a sysctl(like FreeBSD):

http://securityreliks.securegossip.com/2010/10/enabling-ip-forwarding-on-mac-osx/

doing:

```
# sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

as root should enable this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter each computer's address manually in the Network System Preference panel.

eg.

```
Machine A:
IP address: 192.168.1.1 
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Machine B: 
IP address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: "Try to enter each computer's address manually in the Network System Preference panel" I utterly fail to see how that could help - the machines already have IP addresses from the Mac. "You need to enable routing." [09:47:02][bmanica@ariel:~]$ sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1 Already is enabled, and /etc/hostconfig contains IPFORWARDING=-YES-. Still can't ping through the Mac.